# Is it possible to change range of random numbers?

Tags: java, arrays, random

I have an array of non repeating random numbers generated in the range of 0-20 as

```
int[] numbers = {6,14,11,18,13};
```

Now, I want to convert these numbers in the range of 0-10 and I want result as non repeating as well.

Is it possible ?

Any kind of suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Just divide by 2.

Comment: I have thought that before but it gives same result for numbers like 10 and 11

Comment: Either divide each number by 2 as @Turing85 suggested, or just remove all numbers greater than 10.  Either way should work.

Comment: @Sagar Show us the code you used, that doesn't sound right to me.

Comment: What you're asking for is not generally possible.  If it were possible, you could apply the general method to an array of 12 of these random numbers, giving you 12 distinct numbers between 0 and 10 - a contradiction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dividing them by two is a good solution since you have the same size of input and it keeps the uniformity :

For every number every number x in [0;10[, it can come from two numers in [0;20[ : 2*x and 2*x+1.

It will give you the same result for numbers like 10 and 11 but who cares?

Comment: I need non repeating numbers in the array that is the reason

Comment: Then the enunciated problem is missing few details. If you need non repeating numbers then you must have at maximum 10 different values in your input. If you have more you just can't.

Comment: The numbers 0-9 will appear twice as often as 10 in the result.

Comment: I need just 5 values and unique as well. Generated numbers range is 0-20 
and I want to convert these numbers in 0-10 range.

Comment: @Sagar, your problem is changing at each comment ... you should properly ennouce it before refusing anwsers

Comment: @ghilesZ as you say, dividing by 2 cause repeated elements in the resulting array this is what i want to avoid

Answer (score 2):

Here are three methods that I have come up with:

```
// divide by 2
Arrays.stream(numbers).map(x -> x / 2);
// subtract 10 from everything that's > 10
Arrays.stream(numbers).map(x -> x > 10 ? x - 10 : x);
// remove every number that's > 10
Arrays.stream(numbers).filter(x -> x < 10);
```

Now that I know that you don't want repeating numbers, you should probably remove all the duplicates by calling `distinct`.

Comment: Upvoted for the minus 10 option, which should work AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

You could subtract 10 if randomly generated number is greater than 10. I know it's not a proper solution but it'll definitely work for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Java8, you can use the below code to generate unique random numbers:

```
int[] rand = new Random().ints(0, 11).distinct().limit(5).toArray();
```

This code generates 5 unique random numbers ranging from 0 to 10.

Answer (score 0):

The range 0-20 contains 21 numbers, 0-10 contains 11 numbers. So the only solution that leads to uniformly distributed numbers is to take just the numbers in the range 0-10 from the original set and discard numbers in the range 11-20.

Comment: No, I disagree.  If `0-10` be uniformly distributed then why would `0-20` not also be uniformly distributed?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the problem is, if you you try to use all of the numbers from 0-20 when mapping to 0-10, one of the 11 results will be hit less often than the others.

Comment: OK you might be right about that.  The OP should clearly tell us the range and whether each endpoint be open or closed.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate the array in a enhanced for loop with a if condition.You already have non repeated value since you get values from number array.You can use arraylist or any other data structure to store random numbers less than 10.

```
ArrayList<Integer> numberList = new ArrayList<>();
for(int number:numbers){
    if(number<10){
        numberList.add(number);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to use helper array with double values.

The algorithm is next.

1. Create an array with double values from origin array and values are divided by 2.
2. Find the maximum value in the new double array.
3. Scale all values in the new double array. This is should be done by multiplying all values by a coefficient. The coefficient is `coefficient = 10 / max`.
4. Convert the new double array to integer values. One of possible strategy is to round double values.

**Notes**

- It is possible that this solution has some 'bug' and will not work for all combination of random numbers. In that case, the conversion double values to integer should be improved.
- If origin array contains more than 10 values it is not possible to map the array to a new array.

And this is the code for it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] numbers = { 6, 14, 11, 18, 13 };

    // crate a new array with double values
    double[] newNumbers = new double[numbers.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        newNumbers[i] = (double) numbers[i] / 2;
    }

    // get coefficient
    double max = maxValue(newNumbers);
    double coefficient = 10 / max;

    // scale numbers
    for (int i = 0; i < newNumbers.length; i++) {
        newNumbers[i] = newNumbers[i] * coefficient;
    }
    int[] newIntNumbers = new int[newNumbers.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < newNumbers.length; i++) {
        newIntNumbers[i] = (int) Math.round(newNumbers[i]);
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(newNumbers));
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(newIntNumbers));
}

private static double maxValue(double[] array) {
    double max = Double.MIN_VALUE;
    for (double num : array) {
        max = Math.max(max, num);
    }
    return max;
}
```

Comment: works for most of the cases but has some bugs as you have said

Comment: I didn't go deeply in the conversion from double to integer. If you want you can try to improve this line of code `newIntNumbers[i] = (int) Math.round(newNumbers[i]);`. That should resolve those 'bugs'.

Comment: yeah, some time values got repeated for the close numbers like 10, 11 etc

Comment: You can try to scale to minimum value instead to maximum value.